# Stein and Shakarchi, Real Analysis: Exercise 2.14(a)

Tags: real-analysis

> In Exercise 6 of the previous chapter we saw that $m(B)=v_d r^d$, whenever $B$ is a ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^d$ and $v_d=m(B_1)$, with $B_1$ the unit ball. Here we evaluate the constant $v_d$.
>
> (a) For $d=2$, prove using Corollary 3.8 that $$v_2=2\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^{1/2}  \, dx,$$ and hence by elementary calculus, that $v_2=\pi$.

What can I do to prove this? I used $m(B)=v_2 r^2$ and got $v_2=\frac{m(B)} r^2$. And, largely due to Corollary 3.8, $m(B)$ is the volume of the ball which can be represented as an integral. Here is Corollary 3.8:

> **Corollary 3.8** Suppose $f(x)$ is a non-negative function on $\mathbb R^d$, and let $$\mathcal A = \{(x,y) : \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R : 0 \le y \le f(x)\}.$$
> Then:
>
> (i) $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb R^d$ if and only if $\mathcal A$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^{d+1}$.
>
> (ii) If the conditions in $(i)$ hold, then $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) \, dx = m(\mathcal A).$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}^2$. $v_2=m(B_1)$ and $B_1=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le1\}$. Define 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x^2}, & -1\le x\le1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

> $E:=\{x:|x|>1\}\times\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ and so does $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.

Proof: Pick $\varepsilon>0$. Define $\mathcal O_n$ to be the open rectangle $(n,n+1)\times\left(-{\varepsilon\over 2^{|n|+2}},{\varepsilon\over 2^{|n|+2}}\right)\;\forall\;n\in Z:=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1,0\}$. $E\subset\mathcal O:=\bigcup_{n\in Z}\mathcal O_n$. $m(\mathcal O_n)={\varepsilon\over 2^{|n|+1}}\implies m(\mathcal O)=0.75\varepsilon<\varepsilon$. So there exists an open set $\mathcal O:m^*(\mathcal O\setminus E)<\varepsilon$ i.e. $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and as $m(\mathcal O)$ can be made as small as possible $m(E)=0$. A similar proof for $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is easily imaginable.

> If $\mathcal A_-:=\{(x,-y):(x,y)\in\mathcal A\}$ and $\mathcal A$ is Lebesgue mesurable, $m(\mathcal A)=m(\mathcal A_-)$.

Proof: Pick $\varepsilon>0$. $\exists$ open set $\mathcal O:m^*(\mathcal{O\setminus A})<\varepsilon$. The reflection map $R:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $R(x,y)=(x,-y)$ is uniformly continuous w.r.t. euclidean norm ||$\cdot$|| as $||R(x_1,y_1)-R(x_2,y_2)||=||(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)||$ and consequently $O_-=R(\mathcal O)=R^{-1}(\mathcal O)$ is open. $A\subseteq B\implies A_-\subseteq B_-$ and if $I$ is a open interval, $m^*(I)=m^*(I_-)$ so $m^*(\mathcal{O_-\setminus A_-})=m^*(\mathcal{(O\setminus A})_-)=m^*(\mathcal{O\setminus A})$ i.e. $A_-$ is measurable and $m(A_-)=m^*(A_-)=m^*(A)=m(A)$.

> $\mathcal A:=\{(x,y):x\in\mathbb{R},0\le y\le f(x)\}\implies m(B_1)=2m(\mathcal A)$

Proof: As $f$ is continuous and hence measurable by $3.8$ $\mathcal A$ is measurable. $B_1=B\cup B_-$ where $B=\{(x,y):|x|\le1,0\le y\le \sqrt{1-x^2}\}$. So as $B_1$ and $E$ are disjoint and $m(E)=0$, $m(B_1)=m(B\cup B_-)+m(E)=m((B\cup E)\cup(B_-\cup E))=m(\mathcal A\cup \mathcal A_-)=2m(\mathcal A)-m(\mathcal A\cap \mathcal A_-)=2m(\mathcal A)-m(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})=2m(\mathcal A)$.

> $\therefore$ by corollary $3.8$, $v_2=m(B_1)=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$.